# XOrg-config-files in a bumblebee setup

Tags: x11, xorg

I've got a notebook with optimus technology (intel GPU + nvida GPU when needed). I had installed `bumblebee-nvidia`, `nvidia-driver` and `primus`, as every tutorial says to remove all `xorg.conf` files since it's not needed in such a setup.

I'm wondering how `xorg.conf` files are managed/organised. I need to change an option for the intel-gpu but I don't know which file to edit. There is the (main?) folder with some files within it, `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, which just holds other files (like 50-vmmouse.conf for example).

There are also some in `/usr/share/bumblebee/default-conf/` and `/etc/bumblebee/`. All of them including `xorg.conf.nvidia`, `xorg.conf.nouveau` and `xorg.conf.d`.

Which file/folder is correct?

Comment: For me, it has always been something in /etc/, not /usr/. What Distro are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modern `xorg` should just pick all `*.conf` files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and use them.

Xorg can figure out a lot by itself, if you just drop a file with the needed change (an entire **Section**-**EndSection**) into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, Xorg will use that configuration at a higher precedence than the files in `/usr/share/X11/`.

The files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` are reserved for the package manager.  Xorg will look in there *last*.  Never change anything in there, your package manager may overwrite your changes without asking.